# Use "regular" Windows 10/11 as headless VM host

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, hyper-v, kiosk, headless

I'm currently in the position that I have to use Windows on a corporate system but I am allowed to run Linux VMs inside it.  Ideally, however, I'd like to be able to "deactivate" (or restrict) the Windows' desktop environment and boot "straight into" the VM, using the Windows as a more-or-less headless Hyper-V VM host.

My idea would be to use Windows' Kiosk mode to facilitate that and then using the VM's browser to control a HyperV/Windows through a web interface for small administrative stuff.

Has anyone else tried setting up a similar environment?  AFAIK something like this is doable using a Linux host where the host Linux distribution does not much more than initialize QEMU+KVM and boot a guest distribution in full screen that has full control over the I/O hardware incl. mouse, keyboard and monitor as well as other periphery.